# Quick sort runtime speed concerns

Tags: c, performance, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am having something that troubles me. I have my implementation of a quick sort algorithm, but when I test it on an array of integers that has over 30 elements, sorting takes, in my opinion to long. Sometimes even more than 10 seconds, unlike with selection sort, insertion sort and bubble sort, which are faster on 10000 elements than quick sort on 100 elements.

Here is my solution, please give advice :)

```
void kvikSort(int a[], int l, int d) {
    int i, k;

    if (l >= d)
        return;

    k = l;
    swap(&a[l], &a[(l + d) / 2]);

    for (i = l + 1; i <= d; i++)
        if (a[i] < a[l])
            swap(&a[++k], &a[i]);
    swap(&a[l], &a[k]);

    kvikSort(a, 0, k-1);
    kvikSort(a, k+1, d);

}
```

EDIT: I am using GCC v 4.7.2 on my Linux Mint 14, proc: intel core2duo e7400

EDIT: My other algorithms:

```
void selectionSort(int a[], int n) {
    int i, j, min;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        min = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            if (a[j] < a[min])
                min = j;
        if (min != i)
            swap(&a[min], &a[i]);
    }
}


void insertionSort(int a[], int n) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j > 0 && a[j] < a[j-1]; j--)
            swap(&a[j], &a[j-1]);
}


void bubbleSort(int a[], int n) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
            if (a[j] > a[j+1])
                swap(&a[j], &a[j+1]);
}


void swap(int *i, int *j) {
    int tmp;

    tmp = *i;
    *i = *j;
    *j = tmp;
}
```

EDIT: Maybe I should mention that in my test program I am first outputing randomly generated array to a text file, then sorted array to another text file. So it is certainly running slow, but that's not the problem, the problem is that quick sort runs a lot slower than the rest.

Comment: Quicksort is susceptible to some pathological cases that are O(N^2); you are probably running into these. Are your starting sets random, or perhaps sorted or reverse-sorted?

Comment: Might have to look at your other algorithms, but smaller sets of data quicksort can be slower than others because of recursion.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Even then, for 100 elements, it shouldn't take longer than a millisecond or two.

Comment: Did you shuffle the input array beforehand? It could be that the pivot selection at every call is poor.

Comment: Yes, I test on an randomly generated array. I set element valuse using random() function.

Comment: Although, 10 seconds for 30 `int`s does not pass the smell test to me.

Comment: If there are N=30 elements, N^2 is 900. On a machine built in the last 20 years, that should take a lot less than 10 seconds. Even 10000 elements, N^2 = 100M operations, which isn't that many...

Comment: How do you define `swap`?

Comment: Quicksort is _notoriously_ fragile (a small change can break it completely, or make it go off into lala-land "sorting" outside the place it is supposed to sort, and so on). Check that your program _really_ sorts, doesn't wander off out of the array, and doesn't go out of the assigned range.

Comment: That's not a quicksort algorithm. quicksort partitions the elements into those smaller than the pivot and those larger than the pivot.

Comment: @JimBalter This one does. It's not the usual partitioning from both ends, but it swaps the elements smaller than the pivot into the first slots in the array, and what's at least as large in the last.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, ok. But why go for such a crappy implementation with extra swaps when the nested loop implementation is so well known and so efficient?

Comment: "Quicksort is notoriously fragile (a small change can break it completely, or make it go off into lala-land "sorting" outside the place it is supposed to sort, and so on)" -- Such small changes, known as *bugs*, can cause any algorithm or program to have such problems. quicksort is not unusually prone to them.

Comment: @JimBalter I don't know. I remember that that was the first partitioning loop I saw, though. I suspect it is considered easier to get right - and judging by how many broken implementations I have seen here, it may well be.

Comment: I find the optimal inner loop ... search from left for element >= pivot, search from right for element <= pivot, swap them ... is symmetric, logical, and easy to implement correctly with just a little care for the boundary conditions -- it's also a good exercise for learning to take such care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
void kvikSort(int a[], int l, int d) {
int i, k;

if (l >= d)
    return;

k = l;
swap(&a[l], &a[(l + d) / 2]);

for (i = l + 1; i <= d; i++)
    if (a[i] < a[l])
        swap(&a[++k], &a[i]);
swap(&a[l], &a[k]);

>>> kvikSort(a, 0, k-1);
kvikSort(a, l, k-1);
kvikSort(a, k+1, d);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your first recursive call

```
kvikSort(a, 0, k-1);
```

has the wrong lower bound, it should be

```
kvikSort(a, l, k-1);
```

With a lower bound of 0, you re-sort the initial part of the array again and again.

Comment: Pff... now it finishes sorting 10000 elements array before I even hit enter :D